# Backtrack operations and operands in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I'm working towards analyzing the used instructions. Given I have found
an instruction of interest, I want to backtrack all the used operations and
variables. Given for example the following loop in LLVM IR.

```
%i.01 = phi i32 [ 0, %0 ], [ %4, %2 ]
%3 = icmp eq i32 %i.01, 0
%bar.foobar.i = select i1 %3, void ()* @bar, void ()* @foobar
tail call void %bar.foobar.i() #2
%4 = add nuw nsw i32 %i.01, 1
%exitcond = icmp eq i32 %4, 10
br i1 %exitcond, label %1, label %2
```

I'm interested for example in all involved data in the last branch. The condition is computed one instruction before using an `ICompInst` which involves variable `%4` and a constant `10`. `%4` is computed one step before using an addition. And so on and so forth...

Given I found the instruction of interest, in this case the `BranchInst`, I want to start my backtracking.

```
if(BranchInst* BI = dyn_cast<BranchInst>(&I)) {
  if(BI->isConditional()) {
    backtrack(BI, &I);
  }
}
```

To implement such an algorithm, I have two questions. Having the branch instruction, how can I get the condition to start the backtracking?
Second, how can I determine if the condition is used in a previous instruction? To understand it easier, I have the following pseudo code:

```
void backtrack(BranchInst* BI, Instruction* I) {
  Value* condition = BI->getCondition();
  Instruction* prevInst = I;

  do {
    prevInst = prev(prevInst);
    if(prevInst->prevInst(condition)) {
      backTrackOperand(prevInst->getOperand(0), prevInst);
      backTrackOperand(prevInst->getOperand(1), prevInst);
      break;
    }
  } while(1);  
}

void backTrackOperand(Value* operand, Instruction* I) {
  Instruction* prevInst = I;

  do {
    prevInst = prev(prevInst);
    if(prevInst->usesOperand(operand)) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

So how could I implement the function `getCondition()`, `computesCondition()`, and `usesOperand()`?

Answer (score 0):

- getCondition() is getOperand(0).
- I don't see computesCondition() in you code?
- usesOperand() is something like `llvm::find_if(prevInst->operands(), [&] (Uses &U) { return isa<Instruction>(&U) && cast<Instruction>(&U) == I; });`. But note also that from the conditional or any value, you can easily find all the uses.